# Lua string manipulation pattern matching alternative "|"

Tags: string, parsing, lua, lua-patterns

Is there a way I can do a string pattern that will match `"ab|cd"` so it matches for either `"ab"` or `"cd"` in the input string. I know you use something like `"[ab]"` as a pattern and it will match for either `"a"` or `"b"`, but that only works for one letter stuff.

Note that my actual problem is a lot more complicated, but essentially I just need to know if there is an OR thing in Lua's string manipulation. I would actually want to put other patterns on each sides of the  OR thing, and etc. But if it works with something like `"hello|world"` and matches `"hello, world!"` with both `"hello"` and `"world"` then it's great!

Comment: I'm not sure it can be easily accomplished using built-in pattern matching. If you need to perform complex parsing/matching using Lua, you may try lpeg: http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/

Comment: @peterm Yes, this is quite easy with lpeg! `(lpeg.P("foo") + "bar"):match(input)`

Answer (score 5):

Using logical operator with Lua patterns can solve most problems. For instance, for the regular expression `[hello|world]%d+`, you can use

```
string.match(str, "hello%d+") or string.match(str, "world%d+")
```

The shortcut circuit of `or` operator makes sure the string matches `hello%d+` first, if if fails, then matches `world%d+`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately [Lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1) are not regular expressions and are less powerful. In particular they don't support alternation (that vertical bar `|` operator of Java or Perl regular expressions), which is what you want to do.

A simple workaround could be the following:

```
local function MatchAny( str, pattern_list )
    for _, pattern in ipairs( pattern_list ) do
        local w = string.match( str, pattern )
        if w then return w end
    end
end


s = "hello dolly!"
print( MatchAny( s, { "hello", "world", "%d+" } ) )

s = "cruel world!"
print( MatchAny( s, { "hello", "world", "%d+" } ) )

s = "hello world!"
print( MatchAny( s, { "hello", "world", "%d+" } ) )

s = "got 1000 bucks"
print( MatchAny( s, { "hello", "world", "%d+" } ) )
```

**Output:**

```
hello
world
hello
1000
```

The function `MatchAny` will match its first argument (a string) against a list of Lua patterns and return the result of the first successful match.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on peterm's suggestion, lpeg also provides a `re` module that exposes a similar interface to lua's standard `string` library while still preserving the extra power and flexibility offered by lpeg.

I would say try out the `re` module first since its syntax is a bit less esoteric compared to lpeg. Here's an example usage that can match your hello world example:

```
dump = require 'pl.pretty'.dump
re = require 're'


local subj = "hello, world! padding world1 !hello hello hellonomatch nohello"
pat = re.compile [[
  toks  <-  tok (%W+ tok)*
  tok   <-  {'hello' / 'world'} !%w / %w+
]]

res = { re.match(subj, pat) }
dump(res)
```

which would output:

```
{
  "hello",
  "world",
  "hello",
  "hello"
}
```

If you're interested in capturing the position of the matches just modify the grammar slightly for positional capture:

```
tok   <-  {}('hello' / 'world') !%w / %w+
```